# I am faceing problem with this error

Tags: java, struts

I am using Struts application while running welcome page is run successfully after that the following error is appear

**description** :The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
**eception**

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV

any idea whats the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do two things:

1)check  classpath

2)check that standard.jar is added in WEB-INF/lib.